How can I use Github-App(like `DiffLens`) to obtain code from a private repository?(only on the browser)

I have created the app according to the document. (Registering a GitHub App)
webhook. (Building a GitHub App that responds to webhook events)
JWT(generate by python). (Generating a JSON Web Token (JWT) for a GitHub App)

then I try to test url
<script data-description="Github-App">
  function testJWT() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.timeout = 5000;
      xhr.open(
        "GET",
        PR.head.repo.blobs_url.replace("{/sha}", `/${PR.head.sha}`)
      );
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${JWT}`);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-GitHub-Api-Version", `2024-11-26`);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.response);
          } else {
            console.error(xhr.response);
            alert("fail!");
            resolve();
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    });
  }

  testJWT();
</script>

and get fail
{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest",
  "status": "401"
}

I don't know where I went wrong, can someone tell me

I also tried octokit-App octokit-Octokit octokit-createAppAuth OAuth2 key/secret all faild (401)


xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", \Bearer ${JWT}`);- did you insert a static value here? Or where isJWT` supposed to come from?

@C3roe I obtained JWT through the Python generation method provided on the Github Docs

Okay, but did you insert the static value in that place in your actual code? Or is your code literally as it reads above, \Bearer ${JWT}``? If it is the latter, then where's that variable?

@C3roe Yes, I inserted the actual JWT value, this value involves safety and timeliness issues, which I did not write down. I already know what the problem is. Accessing the GitHub API cannot be done directly using JWT, but requires using the access_token obtained by JWT
